# Query with rownum got slow

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g

I have got a table `table` with 21 millions records of which 20 millions meet the criterion `col1= 'text'`. I then started iteratively to set the value of col2 to a value unequal to NULL. After I have mutated 10 million records, the following query got slow, that was fast in the beginning:

```
SELECT T_PK
  FROM (SELECT T_PK
         FROM table
         WHERE col1= 'text' AND col2 IS NULL
         ORDER BY T_PK DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
```

I noticed that as soon as I remove the `DESC`, the whole order by clause `ORDER BY T_PK DESC` or the whole outer query with the condition `WHERE ROWNUM < 100` it is fast again (fast means a couple of seconds, < 10s).

The execution plan looks as follows:
[image]

where the index full scan descending index is performed on the PK of the table. Besides the index on the PK, I have an index defined on `col2`.

What could be the reason that the query was fast and then got slow? How can I make the query fast regardless of how many records are already set to non-null value?

Comment: you're selecting across commits, which means you're reading from rollback.  Perhaps tell your DBAs what you're trying to do (a heads up anyway) and run a single update statement

Comment: Now that the data in `col2` is looking very different than it did before, you might benefit from gathering table statistics using `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS`. You might also want to re-create your index on `col2` to allow lookups by `NULL`: `DROP   INDEX index_on_col2;
CREATE INDEX index_on_col2 ON table (col2, '1');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT T_PK
FROM (SELECT T_PK
      FROM table
      WHERE col1= 'text' AND col2 IS NULL
      ORDER BY T_PK DESC
     ) t
WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
```

The optimal index is `table(col1, col2, t_pk)`.

I think the problem is that the optimizer has a choice of two indexes -- either for the `where` clause (`col1` and -- probably -- `col2`) or one on `t_pk`.  If you have a single index that handles both clauses, then performance should improve.

One reason that the `DESC` might make a difference is where the matching rows lie.  If all the matching rows are in the first 100,000 rows of the table, then when you order descending, the query might have to throw out 20.9 million rows before finding a match.

Answer (score -1):

I think Burleson explained this quite nicely:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_tuning_rownum_equals_one.htm

Beware!
This use of rownum< can cause performance problems. Using rownum may change the all_rows optimizer mode for a query to first_rows, causing unexpected sub-optimal execution plans.  One solution is to always include an all_rows hint when using rownum to perform a top-n query.